# How to properly setup my git $PATH on my mac (I did, but need to understand how it really works)?

Tags: macos, git, unix, path, installation

I installed GIT from the site on my mac, but git --version gave me the old installation (I guess xcode installation). So I solved doing this:

- create a ~/.bash_profile file
- write:

  export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
- restart the terminal

Though, I think there's something in my configuration I could better setup.

My current echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

So IT WORKS, but it's quite a mess, since I've got 2
/usr/local/bin AND an /usr/local/git/bin

Also, I cannot understand WHY now it works, since /usr/local/bin only contains bbedit commands:

- bbdiff
- bbedit
- bbfind

---

I do not know very well all the path-config files and the real order they are read. I only know a few unix commands..
My current files in ~/ are:

~/.profile:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ];
then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

~/bashrc:

```
. ~/bin/dotfiles/bashrc
```

then in . ~/bin/dotfiles/bashrc

```
. ~/bin/dotfiles/bash/env
. ~/bin/dotfiles/bash/config
. ~/bin/dotfiles/bash/aliases
```

and in . ~/bin/dotfiles/bash/env:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

. ~/bin/dotfiles/bash/config is just empty

and . ~/bin/dotfiles/bash/aliases contains some alias commad.

Anyway, it SHOULD have read ~/bin/dotfiles/bash/env, but it doesn't. Or it reads it only after /etc/paths

~/.bash_profile is read first instead.

My current /etc/paths content:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

---

Can anyone explain me the these mechanics? :P Or Maybe I should post this question to some Unix group?

Answer (score 2):

When you type any command on a *NIX shell, the shell tries to resolve that command using the `$PATH`. Say your path is `/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`, then this happens:

```
$ foo
- Does /usr/bin/foo exist? No.
- Does /usr/local/bin/foo exist? No.
- Does foo exist in the current working directory?
```

In other words, it looks at each `$PATH` element in turn and tries to find the executable you asked for there. This is the reason the typical `configure`-`make`-`make install` procedure starts with a `./configure`, to make explicit that you want to run the `configure` executable *in the current directory*, not some system-wide command.

To figure out which `foo` it's actually choosing in the end, run:

```
$ which foo
```

You can run any command explicitly by providing its full path:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/foo  # overrides /usr/bin/foo, should it exist
```

The `export PATH=...:$PATH` directive in your initialization scripts is simply prepending certain paths to your path, allowing you to override the precedence in which order commands are resolved. It's not ideal that `/usr/local/bin` is in there twice, but it's not really a problem either. You *should* take care not to let your path grow too long, since that may result in a lot of lookups for every command and may screw with your head, too.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) for a comprehensive walkthrough of bash config files' loading order.